# unable to resolve the error in bfs implementation

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I've written bfs for finding the shortest paths to every other node:

```
queue<int> q;
dist[s] = 0; // maintains the distance of vertices from s(source).
q.push(s);
while(!q.empty()){
    int src = q.front();
    q.pop();
    vis[src] = 1;          // visited array to keep track of nodes which have been visited
    
    for(int i=0; i<adj[src].size(); i++){ // adj is an adjacency list
        if(!vis[adj[src][i]]){
            q.push(adj[src][i]);
            dist[adj[src][i]] = 6+dist[src];
        }
    }
}
```

This gives wrong anwer and timeout for some unknown testcases.
but when i'm doing this, it passes all the testcase:

```
queue<int> q;
dist[s] = 0;
vis[s] = 1;
q.push(s);
while(!q.empty()){
    int src = q.front();
    q.pop();
    
    for(int i=0; i<adj[src].size(); i++){
        if(!vis[adj[src][i]]){
            q.push(adj[src][i]);
            dist[adj[src][i]] = 6+dist[src];
            vis[adj[src][i]] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not able to figure out why is this happening.

question link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach/problem

Comment: It appears to me that your question does not give any indication on what you have done to try to diagnose the problem, and you just mention "in some case" but it is unclear what case you are talking about - it might be the case that you don't know what case that is - even then it would be a good idea to let us know "on some unknown test cases it fails" instead of saying just in some case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you name the array `vis`, it stands for `is_node_visited`, and you would like to have `is_node_visited[n]` to be true if and only if node `n` is visited.

This is the problem. The right notion for BFS is `is_node_enqueued`. We would like to have `is_node_enqueued[n]` to be true if and only if the node `n` was ever enqueued. The second code does exactly that (except the array is still confusingly called `vis`).

The reason why you need `is_node_enqueued` instead of `is_node_visited` is that you may enqueue the same node twice. Here is a simple example of how that could happen:

```
N1 -> N2
N1 -> N3
N2 -> N4
N3 -> N4
```

And we start the 'BFS' with N1.

- When `N1` is visited, it enqueues `N2` and `N3`.
- When `N2` is visited, it enqueues `N4`.
- When `N3` is visited, N4 is not visited yet.

Here is the interesting time - if you used the former (i.e. incorrect notion) to stop enqueuing only when `N4` is visited. The `N4` will be enqueued again. If you use the correct notion below, then the algorithm would notice `N4` is already enqueued and will not enqueue it again.

The linear performance of BFS is built on top of the premise that a node is processed exactly once. If we use the incorrect version, we break that assumption, and therefore you are not processing the graph in linear time anymore. That is why you are getting time outs.

In general, for diagnosing issues like this. A fruitful approach is to generate some random inputs. Run both programs until they produce different results, and debug through what caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks. actually the test cases where it fails was impossible to handle manually and I couldn't think this test case.